Bashful output in custom command
I'm using bashful to read exif data from images to add to the list of figures. This is a minimal working example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \bash
        exiftool -p '"$ImageDescription" by $Artist, $CopyrightNotice' test.jpg > dynamic_caption.txt
    \END

    \newread\file
    \openin\file=dynamic_caption.txt
    \read\file to \dynamiccaption
    \closein\file

    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{images/test.jpg}
        \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\dynamiccaption}
    \end{figure}

    \listoffigures
\end{document}

What I really need is to use this inside a command (ultimately, the image path would become an argument for the command):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\testCommand}{
  % same as above
}

\begin{document}
    \testCommand
    \listoffigures
\end{document}

This doesn't work. The error is:
! Use of \bashIII doesn't match its definition.
<recently read> e
             
l.25 \testCommand

My assumption is that the \bash \END construct doesn't work inside a command, but I'm not sure whether that's the case, why that's the case, and how I could work around it.
Tried with pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex.

can you reproduce this with one of the standard images we have access to? (not sure whether any would have exif data, though.) but I'd assume the package reads the command in verbatim mode and most likely needs to see that \END explicitly, so it won't work to wrap it into an (ordinary) command.

Works for me, but note that I used no indentation!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\bash
exiftool -p '"$ImageDescription" by $Artist, $CopyrightNotice' Palmeiras.jpg > dynamic_caption.txt
\END

\newread\file
\openin\file=dynamic_caption.txt
\read\file to \dynamiccaption
\closein\file

\begin{figure}[h!]

\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Palmeiras.jpg}
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\dynamiccaption}

\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}


On the other hand, I don't find this the best approach. Here's an expl3 based one.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\getimageattributes}{mm}
 {% #1 = list of attribute names, #2 = image
  \martin_attr_get:nn {#1} {#2}
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\useimageattribute}{m}
 {% #1 = attribute name
  \prop_item:Nn \l__martin_attr_prop {#1}
 }

\clist_new:N \l__martin_attr_keys_clist
\tl_new:N \l__martin_attr_tl
\prop_new:N \l__martin_attr_prop

\cs_new_protected:Nn \martin_attr_get:nn
 {
  % prepare the command line
  \clist_clear:N \l__martin_attr_keys_clist
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#1}
   {
    \clist_put_right:Nn \l__martin_attr_keys_clist { ##1={$##1} }
   }
  % call exiftool and store it
  \exp_args:Ne \sys_get_shell:nnN
   { exiftool~-p~'\clist_use:Nn \l__martin_attr_keys_clist {,}'~#2 } % the command
   {} % the setup
   \l__martin_attr_tl % storage bin
  % store in a property list
  \exp_args:NNV \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l__martin_attr_prop \l__martin_attr_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp!]

\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Palmeiras.jpg}

\getimageattributes{ImageDescription,Artist,CopyrightNotice}{Palmeiras.jpg}
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{%
  ``\useimageattribute{ImageDescription}'' by \useimageattribute{Artist},
  \textcopyright~\useimageattribute{CopyrightNotice}}

\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}


The main idea is to leave the formatting to LaTeX, rather than to exiftool, so I basically call
exiftool -p 'ImageDescription={$ImageDescription},Artist={$Artist},CopyrightNotice={$\CopyrightNotice}' <filename>

In the example case, the temporary token list \l__martin_attr_tl will be fed with
ImageDescription={Os jogadores [...]},Artist={CESAR GRECO},CopyrightNotice={CESAR GRECO}

and this data is translated into a property list we can take items from with \useimageattribute.
The image is the triumph of Palmeiras in the season 2023 (twelfth title for the team ⚽️).
If you have many such constructs all using the same attributes, you can define a wrapper command.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\getimageattributes}{mm}
 {% #1 = list of attribute names, #2 = image
  \martin_attr_get:nn {#1} {#2}
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\useimageattribute}{m}
 {% #1 = attribute name
  \prop_item:Nn \l__martin_attr_prop {#1}
 }

\clist_new:N \l__martin_attr_keys_clist
\tl_new:N \l__martin_attr_tl
\prop_new:N \l__martin_attr_prop

\cs_new_protected:Nn \martin_attr_get:nn
 {
  % prepare the command line
  \clist_clear:N \l__martin_attr_keys_clist
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#1}
   {
    \clist_put_right:Nn \l__martin_attr_keys_clist { ##1={$##1} }
   }
  % call exiftool and store it
  \exp_args:Ne \sys_get_shell:nnN
   { exiftool~-p~'\clist_use:Nn \l__martin_attr_keys_clist {,}'~#2 } % the command
   {} % the setup
   \l__martin_attr_tl % storage bin
  % store in a property list
  \exp_args:NNV \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l__martin_attr_prop \l__martin_attr_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% a wrapper command
\NewDocumentCommand{\addimage}{O{}m}{%
  \begin{figure}[htp!]
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
  \getimageattributes{ImageDescription,Artist,CopyrightNotice}{#2}
  \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{%
    ``\useimageattribute{ImageDescription}'' by \useimageattribute{Artist},
    \textcopyright~\useimageattribute{CopyrightNotice}}
  \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\addimage[width=0.5\textwidth]{Palmeiras.jpg}

\listoffigures

\end{document}


This is awesome. Thank you so much!
